# Python not looping properly over xml file

Tags: python, xml, loops

I'm having difficultly getting python to loop / iterate over an xml file. I am able to load the file and get to each element, but the variable assignment (inside an inner loop) never seems to move past the first pass. Code below / output is below. Any constructive help is appreciated.

```
srv_xmldoc = minidom.parse('servers.xml')
server_list = srv_xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('server')
for srv in server_list:
print srv  #To verify that I'm moving down the list
attribute_list = srv_xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('element')
for e in attribute_list:
        #Setup the server field entries
        server = attribute_list[0].attributes['name'].value
        username = attribute_list[1].attributes['name'].value
        password = attribute_list[2].attributes['name'].value
        delimeter = attribute_list[3].attributes['name'].value
        remotePath =attribute_list[4].attributes['name'].value
        fileType = attribute_list[5].attributes['name'].value

#Start processing this server entry
process_entry(server, username, password, delimeter, remotePath, fileType)
```

The output looks like:

```
<DOM Element: server at 0x7f09410d6248>
192.168.1.6
<DOM Element: server at 0x7f09410d6d88>
192.168.1.6
<DOM Element: server at 0x7f09410d7908>
192.168.1.6
```

As you can see, srv variable keeps changing but the IP address does not.

A sample of the xml file is below:

```
    <servers>
    <server>
            <element name="192.168.1.6"></element>
            <element name="server"></element>
            <element name="blah0"></element>
            <element name="|"></element>
            <element name="/path/to/data/"></element>
            <element name=".psv"></element>
    </server>
    <server>
            <element name="192.168.1.7"></element>
            <element name="server2"></element>
            <element name="blah"></element>
            <element name=";"></element>
            <element name="/path/to/data/"></element>
            <element name=".csv"></element>
    </server>
    <server>
            <element name="192.168.1.8"></element>
            <element name="server3"></element>
            <element name="blah2"></element>
            <element name=","></element>
            <element name="/path/to/data/"></element>
            <element name=".csv"></element>
    </server>
```

Comment: Will you please include a representative sample of the input XML?

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
attribute_list = srv_xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('element')
```

is the problem. You're grabbing all "element" elements in the document, not all child nodes of the current "server" node. This means that your loop loads the content of the first 6 "element" nodes every time, which is why you aren't seeing the IP address update. You should loop through the childNodes of the server instead, and, if necessary, compare the node name to make sure that it's of the right type.